# Unable to load multicol package on Texmaker

Tags: packages, texmaker

When I put \usepackage{multicol} in the preamble marks me an error "Missing \begin{document}". And when I put it down the \begin{document} line, it says that it only can be used in preamble. So I'm really confused about that.
Here is the code, I have to put the twocolumn option into \documentclass option:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\title{Módulo 1: "Tejido Epitelial de Recubrimiento y Glandular}
\author{Neil Alexis}
\date

\begin{document}

\maketitle
El tejido epitelial consta de un grupo de células muy próximas entre sí, con muy poco espacio entre ellas y cohesionadas por especializaciones de la membrana plasmática. El polo mundial puede dar lugar a diferenciaciones de la membrana plasmática, como microvello sidades, cilios y estercocilios. El polo basal relaciona la célula con el tejido conjuntivo subyacente. A este nivel se desarrolla la membrana basal.
Existen dos grandes categorías de epitelio:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Epitelio de recubrimiento
    \item Epitelio glandular
\end{itemize}

\part{Epitelio de Recubrimiento}
Al menos una capa se encuentra montada sobre la membrana basal, y cuentan con un polo basal el cual está en contacto con la membrana basal y un polo apical que está en la dirección opuesta. Presentan una cohesión con muy poco espacio intercelular. No presentan irrigación vascular, es decir, son avasculares. Poseen un potencial metaplásico o en otras palabras la capcidad de cambiar su morfología además de ser capaces de regenerarse gracias a la mitosis. En resumen:

\begin{itemize}
\item Montado sobre membrana basal
\item Polaridad basal y apical
\item Cohesión: Unión intercelular con escaso espacio entre ellas
\item Avasculares
\item Potencial metaplásico
\item Capacidad regenerativa
\end{itemize}

\section{Criterios de Clasificación}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Morfología célular
\item Números de capas celulares
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Morfología Celular}
\subsubsection{Células planas}
Poseen \textbf{forma irregular} y \textbf{núcleo demarcado sobresaliente}, parecido a un huevo frito. Se puede encontrar en la pleura, alveolos pulmoares e interior de vasos sanguíneos

\subsubsection{Células cúbicas}
La forma de cubo permite al núcleo acaparar más espacio otorgándole una forma esférica. Se pueden encontrar en los túbulos del riñón y ducto glandulares

\end{document}
```

[image: Message error when I load multicol in preamble]
[image: Message error when I load multicol after \begin{document}]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Can you, put, please the whole code to understand your problem?

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the post, I didn't know what was the most effective way to put it so I just copy-pasted there.

Comment: Including `\usepackage{multicol}`, it compiles well for me with pdflatex and Tex Live 2020 in TexStudio 2.12.22

Comment: please, place `\usepackage{multicol}` after `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` and above `\title{}`

Comment: Oh thanks you a lot, do you really fixed my problem!. By the way, why it doesn't work if I put it in another place? I mean, loading a package in the preamble should be enough right?

Comment: Why do you want to use the multicol package in a twocolumn document class?

Comment: In first place I wanted to use multicol but because of the suspicious error that I had, I'd to set the twocolumn option in document class

Answer (score 3):

The package is unrelated to the error, the error is `\date` which takes an argument so it was getting the blank line, but when you added `\usepackage` that was taken as the argument to `\date` and generates multiple spurious errors.

use

`\date{1066}`